# cloning a virtual env into another directory using conda

Tags: shell, conda, cloning

I am working on a shared server and trying to clone a virtual env **myenv** into my **home directory**.

Here are some facts:

```
myenv         /path to my home directory/my profile/.conda/envs/myenv
root        * /opt/conda/4.6.14
```

I currently do not have permissions to install packages into the install area `/opt/conda/4.6.14` and so I am trying to clone the `myenv` into my home directory using this command:

```
conda create -n myenv_clone -p /path to my home directory/myprofile --clone=/opt/conda/4.6.14
```

However, this gives me the error:
conda create error : `--prefix not allowed with -n`

My conda info output :

Current conda install:

```
           platform : linux-64
      conda version : 4.3.16
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.16
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 2.7.16.final.0
   requests version : 2.21.0
   root environment : /opt/conda/4.6.14  (read only)
default environment : /opt/conda/4.6.14
   envs directories : /home/bridge/c/sheth7/.conda/envs
                      /opt/conda/4.6.14/envs
      package cache : /home/bridge/c/sheth7/.conda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
        config file : /home/bridge/c/sheth7/.condarc
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.16 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.16 Linux
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output from `conda config --show envs_dirs pkgs_dirs`.

Comment: Also, what's with the discrepancy between the directory name (4.6.14) and the reported Conda version (4.3.16)? That's pretty old. If you can't update that, perhaps you should consider a Miniconda install of your own and avoid altogether trying to deal with the central one.

Comment: Thanks merv. The version discrepancy was the root of all my problems. I determined that there was an older conda version installed in .local . Removing this older version using `rm -r` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that you can't use both the `--prefix|-p` and `--name|-n` flags together. However, the broader description sounds like this isn't the real issue that needs solving.  In fact, I don't see why you need to clone **myenv** - it's already under your home directory.

Since you don't include your full configuration info (e.g., `conda info`), I can't tell exactly the situation, but on the surface it sounds like the issue isn't with writing to an `envs` directory but instead about the `pkgs` directory.

Have a look at the `conda config --describe envs_dirs pkgs_dirs` documentation. Seeing as you already have **myenv** where it is, I'd guess you want to do something like:

```
conda config --append envs_dirs "/path to my home directory/my profile/.conda/envs"
mkdir -p "/path to my home directory/my profile/.conda/pkgs"
conda config --append pkgs_dirs "/path to my home directory/my profile/.conda/pkgs"
```

Then you should simply be able to use Conda normally.  That is, it will automatically fall back to writing to these directories if you don't have privileges in the higher priority locations. So, you shouldn't even need to clone **myenv** to install packages into it

Comment: Edited the question to include my conda configuration. It looks like I have correctly configured envs_dirs and pkgs_dirs. However, the package installation still takes place on root folder which is inaccessible.

Comment: @sheth7 Was that trying to install to **root**? I don't think that will work, but I'd expect installing to **myenv** to work. Also, what happens when you run `conda create -n myenv_clone --clone myenv`?

Comment: it is unable to find myenv

CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError: Could not find environment: myenv .

[sheth7@autobahn ~]$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:

root                  *  /opt/conda/4.6.14

Comment: @sheth7 I'm confused. What are you reporting in your original question then? How did you list **myenv** in the first place?

Comment: I am able to create myenv by specifying a --prefix but when I try to access it, it can't find it. This indicates an issue with path tracing. However, I am not able to think of solutions. 
Further, one issue was that I was using a csh shell. I changed this to a bash shell. But it is still not working.