# conda install packages to env in prefixed path

Tags: python, shell, conda

I created an environment in a prefixed path using

```
conda create -p ~/myenv python=3.6
```

I activated it using

```
conda activate ~/myenv
```

but when I install a package to it, using

```
conda install pandas
```

It tries to install the package in my `root` folder rather than in my environment.

Comment: I think I may have answered your underlying issue in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57115524/cloning-a-virtual-env-into-another-directory-using-conda.  If not, please update this one with more info. For example, what is the output of `conda install pandas` that indicates to you it is installing in the **root** env?  Generally, on all Conda questions it is best practice to include `conda info` output.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing similar issues:

I determined that there was an older conda version installed in .local . Removing this older version using `rm -r` solved the issue. Caution: Be careful while using the `rm -r`.